# How to get the handle foreground window in server OS?

Tags: c++, windows, server, operating-system, getforegroundwindow

I have been working in a project which checks the foreground window every 5 seconds using GetForegroundWindow(), I have a doubt that if multiple users are logged on at same time(let say windows server OS),

1.Whether the function returns multiple handle for foreground window?

2.Is it possible to check what is the foreground window in each user?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow returns 0 or 1 window handle, not multiple

Comment: My question is it is possible whether we can get the active window in all the users under server OS?